# Is webworker itself multi-thread?

Tags: javascript, html

e.g.

```
 worker.postMessage(data1);
 worker.postMessage(data2);
```

And inside the webwoker,assuming there's quantity of issues to be deal with,would `worker.postMessage(data2)` block before completing the `data1`

Comment: What task is your worker performing? Computation? Ajax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single worker executes its task in queue, i.e. one task at time. Try the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script>

var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.postMessage({ task: 1, iterations: 100 }); // very slow task
worker.postMessage({ task: 2, iterations: 1 }); // very quick task
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
};

</script>
```

worker.js:

```
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < event.data.iterations * 1000 * 1000 * 10; i++) {};
    self.postMessage("Finished task " + event.data.task);
}
```

Ouput:

```
Finished task 1
Finished task 2
```

The tasks are always finished in order, i.e. first the slow one, then the quick one. (If the task were executed in parallel, the second task would finish first with a clear margin.)

(Just to be clear: calling postMessage always blocks in its execution context (as any function call) but effectively returns "immediately", because posting the message itself is very quick operation. That's probably not what you asked.)

Note: Chrome throws a security exception if you try to load the worker.js from local disk, works in Safari & Firefox.